# Running Profiler from Command Line versus Visual Studio

Tags: profiling

I am using Visual Studio 2008 built in profiler and DevPartner .NET profiler. 
I have option of running the profiler from Visual Studio or from command line?

Does anyone know which option is recommended?

Is it correct that running from Visual Studio would take more time compared to running from command line?

Thanks.

Dharmesh.
http://smartsecurity.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out myself that running the profiler from command line is much much better and accurate compared to running it from the IDE. The IDE takes it own time to load and display profiling statistics. Even Microsoft recommends running profiler from command line.

Here is the link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/10/09/using-vsts-2008-memory-allocation-profiling.aspx

Thanks & Regards,
Dharmesh Mehta